# How to get the raw value of an antd form field using antd-mask-input library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I am using [antd-mask-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd-mask-input) library on my Ant Design app to put mask into a field on my [antd form](https://ant.design/components/form/). This antd-mask-input library was built using this [inputmask-core](https://github.com/insin/inputmask-core) library.

Here is an [working example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/rough-tdd-b48pk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) on codesandbox.io. Fill in any value on both fields and open console. Once you click on `Confirm` the value of the fields will be logged on console output.

As you can see, the `phone` const have the value of the field with the mask, but I need it without the mask. There is a [getRawValue()](https://github.com/insin/inputmask-core#getrawvalue--string) method on inputmask-core but I can't figure out how to use it with the `MaskedInput` component provided by [antd-mask-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd-mask-input) library.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Form, Icon, Input, Button } from "antd";
import { MaskedInput } from "antd-mask-input";

const INPUT_ICON_COLOR = "rgba(0,0,0,.25)";

const FormFields = Object.freeze({
  EMAIL: "email",
  PHONE: "phone"
});

class Signup extends Component {
  handleSubmit = e => {
    const { form } = this.props;
    const { validateFields } = form;

    e.preventDefault();

    validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        const a = form.getFieldValue(FormFields.PHONE);
        debugger;

        const phone = values[FormFields.PHONE];
        const email = values[FormFields.EMAIL];

        console.log("phone", phone);
        console.log("email", email);
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { form } = this.props;
    const { getFieldDecorator } = form;

    return (
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          width: "100%",
          flexDirection: "column"
        }}
      >
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className={"login-form"}>
          <Form.Item>
            {getFieldDecorator(FormFields.PHONE, {
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: "Please type value"
                }
              ]
            })(
              <MaskedInput
                mask="(11) 1 1111-1111"
                placeholderChar={" "}
                prefix={
                  <Icon type="phone" style={{ color: INPUT_ICON_COLOR }} />
                }
                placeholder="Phone"
              />
            )}
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item>
            {getFieldDecorator(FormFields.EMAIL, {
              rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please type value" }]
            })(
              <Input
                type={"email"}
                prefix={
                  <Icon type="mail" style={{ color: INPUT_ICON_COLOR }} />
                }
                placeholder="Email"
              />
            )}
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item>
            <Button
              type="primary"
              htmlType="submit"
              className={"login-form-button"}
            >
              Confirm
            </Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Form.create({ name: "signup" })(Signup);
```

[image: Edit rough-tdd-b48pk]

Comment: Try making a small producible example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-antd-styled-template-n8n96, easier to answer and there is a code to play with

Comment: Ok, I will edit this question when done.

Comment: Hi @DennisVash please take a look, the codesandbox is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking [on the source code](https://github.com/antoniopresto/antd-mask-input/blob/master/src/lib/MaskedInput.tsx):

```
export default class MaskedInput extends Component<MaskedInputProps> {
  mask: InputMask;
  input!: HTMLInputElement;
....
}
```

The `InputMask` reference is under the `mask` value, therefore you can get the function like so:

```
this.inputMaskRef.current.mask.getRawValue()
```

Example:

```
class Signup extends Component {
  inputMaskRef = React.createRef();

  handleSubmit = e => {
    ...
    validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        ...
        console.log(this.inputMaskRef.current.mask.getRawValue());
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    ...
    return (
      <Form ...>
        <Form.Item>
          {getFieldDecorator(FormFields.PHONE, {...})(
            <MaskedInput
              ref={this.inputMaskRef}
              mask="(11) 1 1111-1111"
              ...
            />,
          )}
        </Form.Item>
        ...
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit billowing-glade-q024p]

Comment: It helped a lot. After playing a little with your solution on codesandbox I improved your code. My final code is on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/q-59521296-inputmaskreference-2nif2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).